# Android Studio [Recycler View] / ¿Cómo capturar el evento de un botón?

Tags: android, android-studio, eventos

**[PROBLEMA RESUELTO]** Estoy trabajando con un **recycler view horizontal ↔** el cuál tiene **botones** con distintos nombres. Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para **cambiar el nombre** de un TextView (txt_nombre) dependiendo del botón que se haya **tocado** en el Recycler View.

Como verán a continuación en el código, utilizo el método **onClick** de **adaptador_model_recycler_nombre** para intentar cambiar el nombre del Text View, pero por alguna razón el código no funciona ni tampoco la aplicación crashea. Simplemente no hace nada.

**P.D.:** Quiero aclarar que esta forma de seleccionar una vista dentro de un RecyclerView, la probé en esta misma aplicación y **funciona. Excepto en esta actividad** la cual adjunto su código en este post:

```
public class fragment_inicio extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recycler_nombres;
private TextView txt_nombre;

private ArrayList<model_recycler_nombre> array_model_recycler_nombre = 
new ArrayList<>();
private adapter_recycler_nombre adaptador_model_recycler_nombre;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, 
false);

recycler_materias = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_nombre);
txt_nombre = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre_inicio);

recycler_nombre.setLayoutManager(new 
LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));

adaptador_model_recycler_nombre = new 
adapter_recycler_nombre(array_model_recycler_nombre);
recycler_nombre.setAdapter(adaptador_model_recycler_nombre);

//MÉTODO PARA OBTENER LA VISTA SELECCIONADA
adaptador_model_recycler_nombre.setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            String nombre = 
            array_model_recycler_nombre.get(recycler_nombre.
            getChildAdapterPosition(view)).getNombre();

            txt_nombre.setText(nombre);}});
}
```

**Adjunto foto de como se ve la actividad:**
            [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PROBLEMA NRO. 2 (IGNORAR: Resuelto por Bryan GDCA):**
Tengo un problema de **casi** las mismas características por lo que no me pareció correcto crear una **pregunta aparte**.

En otra actividad de mi aplicación tengo un **RecyclerView vertical** con una **imágen** que, **al tocarla**, muestra un **pop-up** (o ventana emergente) con cinco botones. Uno de esos botones debería **cambiar de actividad** al ser tocado. Estoy intentando capturar el evento del clic de ese botón con un .setOnClickListener en la clase de tipo "**adaptador**" del recyclerView. El problema es que el método **startActivity()** ,para abrir una nueva actividad, **no es reconocido** por la clase (supongo que será porque la clase no extiende de **AppCompatActivity**). Lo que necesito es que me ayuden a lograr que **la clase reconozca** el método startActivity para poder cambiar de actividad al tocar un botón que está en un pop-up el cual aparece por tocar una imágen en un Recycler.

**Adjunto el código:**

```
public class adapter_recycler_chats extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter_recycler_chats.ViewHolderDatos> implements 
View.OnClickListener{

private ArrayList<model_recycler_chats> array_model_recycler_chat;
private View.OnClickListener click_listener;
private Context context;

public adapter_recycler_chats(ArrayList<model_recycler_chats> 
array_model_recycler_chat, Context context){
    this.array_model_recycler_chat = array_model_recycler_chat;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public adapter_recycler_chats.ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup 
parent, int viewType) {
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout
.item_row_recycler_chat,null,false);

    view.setOnClickListener(this);

    final ViewHolderDatos holder = new ViewHolderDatos(view,this.context);

//APERTURA DEL POP-UP CUANDO SE TOCA LA IMÁGEN DEL RECYCLER VIEW
    holder.img_foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Dialog dialog_foto;
            dialog_foto = new Dialog(context);
            dialog_foto.setContentView(R.layout.popup_foto_chat);

            Button bt_perfil, bt_mensaje, bt_foto, bt_adjuntar, bt_llamar;
            TextView txt_nombre,txt_profesion;

            bt_perfil = 
dialog_foto.findViewById(R.id.bt_perfil_popup_foto_chat);
            bt_mensaje = 
dialog_foto.findViewById(R.id.bt_foto_popup_foto_chat);
            txt_profesion = 
dialog_foto.findViewById(R.id.txt_profesion_popup_foto_chat);
            txt_nombre = 
dialog_foto.findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre_popup_foto_chat);

//LISTENER DE UN BOTÓN DEL POPUP (ATENCIÓN ACA)
            bt_perfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, 
                    chat_individual.class);
//START-ACTIVITY NO RECONOCIDO (Cannot resolv method 'startActivity')
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });}
    });
    return holder;
}
```

**Adjunto foto de este segundo problema:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 1):

Para tu segundo problema solo añade tu contexto antes del startActivity, algo asi...

context.startActivity(intent);

Tambien tuve algunos problemas como los tuyos hace un tiempo, yo preferi dejar el evento onClick dentro del Adaptador, me genero menos problemas

Comment: Tremendo hermano. Me funcionó perfectamente, gracias infinitas. El primer problema tenes idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: Algo asi, yo implemente el evento onClick pero dentro del adaptador

Comment: Recuerda @TomasM la mejor forma de agradecer si la respuesta te fue útil es marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

Yo implemente el evento onClick dentro del adaptador para un CardView de la siguiente manera....
En mi caso yo abro una ventana de dialogo en donde seteo los textos
Creo que podrias hacer lo mismo para tu caso

```
@Override
public ViewHolderComponentes onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View vista = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_grid_componentes,parent,false);
    final ViewHolderComponentes vHolder = new ViewHolderComponentes(vista);

    myDialog = new Dialog(context);
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_componente);

    vHolder.CardComponent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Seleccion: " + vHolder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView Nombre = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.Dialog_Name_Component);
            TextView Descripcion = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.Dialog_Description_Component);
            TextView Funcionamiento = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.Dialog_Funcionamiento_Component);
            ImageView Imagen = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.Dialog_Img_Component);
            ImageView ImagenSimbolo = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.Dialog_Img_Component_Simbolo);

            Nombre.setText(listaComponentes.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getTxt_title());
            Descripcion.setText(listaComponentes.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getTxt_description());
            Funcionamiento.setText(listaComponentes.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getTxt_funcionamiento());
            Imagen.setImageResource(listaComponentes.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getImg_component());
            ImagenSimbolo.setImageResource(listaComponentes.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getImg_component_simbolo());

            myDialog.show();

        }
    });


    return vHolder;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder pero no puedo utilizar tu código para mi caso.

Comment: Me alegro de poder haberte ayudado aunque sea en uno de tus problemas, suerte